# How to import and create unit test for tasks in apache airflow?

Tags: python, unit-testing, airflow, pytest

I am a complete beginner in airflow and just created a basic airflow.

So, my question is, inside the DAG where we are assigning tasks using PythonOperator, can we create unit test cases for that task. Unit test case on that particular function using pytest is possible, I know, I tried it, but I want to know if it is at all possible to create unit test case for the task instead of that function without actually running and testing for the dag itself.

```
def _process_user(ti):
    user = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="extract_user")
    user = user['results'][0]
    processed_user = json_normalize({
        'firstname': user['name']['first'],
        'lastname': user['name']['last'],
        'country': user['location']['country'],
        'username': user['login']['username'],
        'password': user['login']['password'],
        'email': user['email'] })
    processed_user.to_csv('/tmp/processed_user.csv', index=None, header=False)
 
def _store_user():
    hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id='postgres')
    hook.copy_expert(
        sql="COPY users FROM stdin WITH DELIMITER as ','",
        filename='/tmp/processed_user.csv'
    )
```

The above are the functions.

```
process_user = PythonOperator(
        task_id='process_user',
        python_callable=_process_user
    )
 
    store_user = PythonOperator(
        task_id='store_user',
        python_callable=_store_user
    )
 
    create_table >> is_api_available >> extract_user >> process_user >> store_user
```

The above are the tasks created using that function in PythonOperator. My question is to create a unit test for "process_user" and "store_user" tasks in the dag, without running the entire dag itself.

Because no where online I could find any references to creating unit test for a task, just functions.

Also, is it possible to import these tasks in a separate python file and create test cases in that file, because it will become messy if the dummy tests functions are used in the same file.

Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Could you please tell a bit about why you want to test the operators instead of the callables that you wrote? Operators that are a part of the Airflow's library should be [well-tested](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/tests/operators/test_python.py) by the maintainers; custom operators can be unit-tested as describe in Airflow's [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#unit-tests).

Comment: While funcs return the result, tasks get that result and forward it to next task. Instead of editing the func to unit test, wouldn't it be easier to unit test the task output. That's why I wanted to ask if the tasks, not the operators, could be unit tested. Also, thank you for the documentation link regarding custom operators unit test. Didn't know that was possible!